# Yii2 : Checkbox rules not working at signup for terms and conditions

Tags: php, yii2

On signup, I need a certain message, but for some reason, it fails to show my message.

please help

I have the following rules:

```
['acordul_tc', 'required', 'on' => ['register']],
['acordul_tc', 'integer', 'max' => 1, 'message' => 'my test message'],
```

and the html:

```
<div style='position:relative; float:left; padding:5px;'>
<div style='float:left; padding:5px;'>
    <?php
        echo $form->field($model, 'acordul_tc', 
        ['options' => ['tag' => 'span',], 
        'template' => "{input}"])->checkbox(['checked' => false]);
    ?>
</div>
<div style='float:left; padding:5px;'>
    <?php
        echo \Yii::t('user', 'acordul_tc_start') . 
        Html::a(Yii::t('diverse', 'Termenii si Conditiile'), 
               ['site/terms-and-conditions']) . 
            \Yii::t('user', 'acordul_tc_end');
    ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
<?php
    echo $form->field($model, 'acordul_tc', 
         ['template' => "{error}"])
         ->error();
?>
```

Comment: You have blindly accepted the answer just because it shows error message. Ideally the checkbox must become RED is not checked along with the error.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to show error message when checkbox is not checked, try this rule

```
 ['acordul_tc', 'required', 'on' => ['register'], 'requiredValue' => 1, 'message' => 'my test message']
```

This means that the attribute is required and must be equal to 1, else display error with your message.

Comment: This does not highlight the checkbox as 'Red'. The above implementation only gives error message. What to do to highlight checkbox as 'Red'?

Comment: @olchick.. Hi i want to make my checkbox as checked by default. I tried this but does not help.. `<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox(['checked' => true]); ?>`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz to have the checkbox checked by default set the model attribute to the required value prior to generating the input field. i.e. $model->status = 1

Comment: @zumek thank you for reply.. i had asked this long back.. will use this if required in future.

Answer (score 2):

1. The Accepted answer does not mark required Checkbox as 'RED' colored.
2. It only shows the error message below the checkbox which is partially accepted, the solution must be acceptable only if it shows proper validation effects on UI and not just the message.
3. Below is the code change need to be done on FORM to get expected output for End User.

   ```
   echo $form->field($model, 'acordul_tc', 
                   ['options' => ['tag' => 'span'], 
                   template' => "{input}"]
               )
             ->checkbox(['checked' => false, 'required' => true]);
   ```
4. Below is the image that explains all.

[image]

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, it shows the message and it marks checkbox as red. Here's my screenshot https://monosnap.com/file/5TsxoX6gunITaQFH28dbZ5liYpxMYq.png

Answer (score 2):

**in model>rules function**

```
[['acordul_tc'], 'compare', 
    'compareValue' => true,
    'operator' => '==',
    'when' => function ($data) {
        return $data->acordul_tc== 1;
    }
],
```

Comment: This worked for only with `enableClientValidation`, this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/39342554/5494094 works without it, and the `'operator' => '=='` is not required.