# Yii2 making checkbox required doesn't work

Tags: php, yii2

This is my form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?php echo $form->field($invite, 'email')->textInput([
    'id' => 'register-email', 
    'placeholder' => Yii::t('UserModule.views_auth_login', 'email')]);
?>

<?php echo $form->field($invite, 'check')->checkbox([
    'id' => 'check', 
    'uncheck' => null])->label(
            Yii::t('UserModule.views_auth_login', 'I have read and accept') . ' <a href="#">' 
            . Yii::t('UserModule.views_auth_login', 'Terms & Conditions') . '</a> ' 
            . Yii::t('UserModule.views_auth_login', 'and') 
            . ' <a href="#">' . Yii::t('UserModule.views_auth_login', 'Privacy Policy') 
            . '</a>' . '.');
?>
    <hr>

    <?php
         echo \humhub\widgets\AjaxButton::widget([
            'label' => Yii::t('UserModule.views_auth_login', 'Register'),
            'ajaxOptions' => [
            'type' => 'POST',
            'beforeSend' => new yii\web\JsExpression('function(){ setModalLoader(); }'),
            'success' => 'function(html){ $("#globalModal").html(html); }',
            'url' => Url::to(['/user/auth/login']),
        ],
        'htmlOptions' => [
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'registerBtn'
        ]
    ]);
    ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['email'], 'required'],
        [['email'], 'unique'],
        [['email'], 'email'],
        [['email'], 'unique', 'targetClass' => \humhub\modules\user\models\User::className(), 'message' => Yii::t('UserModule.base', 'E-Mail is already in use! - Try forgot password.')],
        [['check'], 'required'],
        [['check'], 'compare', 'compareValue' => 1, 'message'=>'bla-bla-bla'],
    ];
}
```

How do I do my form valid only if both 'email' is not empty an valid and 'check' is checked? Now the issue is 'check' does not validate. Thanks.

Comment: Delete `'uncheck' => null` and the `compare` rule and see if does make any difference.

Comment: Hi Kostas, it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `compare` rule and update the required rule as shown below.

`[['check'], 'required', 'requiredValue' => 1, 'message'=>'bla-bla-bla'],`

Comment: This worked for me with `Yii2 v~2.0.14` and `"dektrium/yii2-user": "^0.9.14"` rules validator.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Add this method in your model:

```
public function validateCheckWithEmail($attribute, $params) 
{
    if (empty($this->check) && !empty($this->email) && $this->validateAttribute($this, 'email')) {
        $this->addError($attribute, $this->getAttributeLabel($attribute).' field cannon be empty.');
    }
}
```

In your rules add:

```
[['check'], 'validateCheckWithEmail', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false],
```